# changing the behaviour of predefined variables in php

Tags: php, session-variables, predefined-variables

I have made a session management library in PHP that stores session data in databases using functions rather than the trivial `$_SESSION['key'] = value`.

To store the data, the user would use `storeData($key, $value)` function
To retrieve the data, the user would use `getData($key)` function.

However I want my users to still keep using `$_SESSION` rather than functions so that old codes do not need to be modified.

Is there a way that if the user uses `$_SESSION`, I can somehow get those values and apply to my functions. So the user still would think that they are using PHP's `$_SESSION` but in the background they actually would be using my functions.

Comment: Have a look at session_set_save_handler, http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php